# Manually render a route's URL

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to render a page containing a link whose href value is `"javascript:#{mySmallJsSnippet}"`, where `mySmallJsSnippet` is some Javascript that adds to the current page a `<script>` tag with `src="http://e.g.com/static/myFullJsFile.js"`.

I have a few questions around this, but the main one is embarrassingly simple:

Given a route -- e.g. `StaticR myFullJsFile_js` -- how do I render the route's URL as a String so I can embed it in `mySmallJsSnippet`?  Basically, I don't know how to do in my handler code what Yesod's template rendering machinery does automatically to every `@{fooBaR}`.

I suspect it has to do with `renderRoute` and `joinPath`, but I'm not using `joinPath` correctly.  My best guess so far was to import `App` from Foundation.hs and pass that as `joinPath`'s first parameter -- no go.

I'll keep looking, but it would be great to have some help, as I'm sure this is simple stuff for someone who's experienced with Yesod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`getUrlRender`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.5/yesod-core-1.4.32/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:getUrlRender) from `Yesod.Handler`:

```
getUrlRender :: GHandler sub master (Route master -> Text)
```

In your case it will look like this:

```
do render <- getUrlRender  
   let renderedUrl = render $ StaticR myFullJsFile_js
```

The function will render your type-safe `Route` into plain `Text`, that you can insert e.g. into a script.
This way you will loose the correctness guaranty provided by using `@{ ... }`, so you should fall back on it only if necessary.

There is also a description of this function in the [Yesod Book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/routing-and-handlers).

Comment: Not bad for your first SO answer :)  Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I'm curious -- what do you mean "you shouldn't play around with it"?

Comment: Thanks for your edit.  I'm still not sure I understand though.  Won't it be guaranteed that the URL I'm `printf`ing into my Javascript snippet is the correct URL for that route?  Of course that's different from saying that the Javascript snippet will be correct in other respects; I understand that there are no guarantees of that.